# Image of arbitrary ideal under quotient map

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

[image: Aluffi - Algebra Chapter 0, Exercise III.3.3.3]

Proposition 3.11 being the third isomorphism theorem for Rings.

I know that in a Ring there is a correspondence between ideals containing $I$ and the ideals of $R/I$. But I'm not sure about the image of an arbitrary ideal.

My guess is that $\varphi(J)=\varphi(J+I)$, still I feel uncomfortable with this statement since then $(R/I)/(J/I) \cong R/J$ which I know isn't right. So why is it that $\overline{J} = (I+J)/I$ and not $\overline{J} = J/I$?

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $J\not\supseteq I$, writing $J/I$ doesn't make much sense. On the other hand
$$
\{x+I:x\in J\}=\{x+I:x\in I+J\}
$$
is true and $I+J\supseteq I$.

Your $\overline{J}$ is indeed $(I+J)/I$ and
$$
\frac{R/I}{\overline{J}}=\frac{R/I}{(I+J)/I}\cong \frac{R}{I+J}
$$

Comment: Fair enough. But why doesn't J/I make sense. Isn't this simply a coset of abelian subgroups?

Comment: @MrHolmes You can interpret it as a set of cosets, not as a quotient group.